# How to call some method every time user enters some model admin in django?

Tags: python, django

Well, the question speaks for itself.

I thought about something like this, but it's not working.

```
class SystemAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = SystemAdminForm
    refresh()

    def refresh(self, request, obj):
    avahi = AvahiServiceDetector(self.update)


    def update(self, name, address, port):
        ip = IP.objects.get_or_create(address=address)


name 'refresh' is not defined
```

Comment: Do you want to call it just once or for each item to be returned by the admin? (Because you're using obj in refresh's definition)

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You should explain what the problem is actually and what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling refresh from global namespace, which is of course not defined. What you would need to do is to call your method in `__init__`:

```
class SystemAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = SystemAdminForm

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SystemAdmin,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.refresh()

    def refresh(self, request, obj):
        avahi = AvahiServiceDetector(self.update)


    def update(self, name, address, port):
        ip = IP.objects.get_or_create(address=address)
```

Comment: This actually works better, because get_form not called only once, when user enter this page, but more than that.

calling refresh in init is obvious solution, but when I tried it myself, I didn't knew what arguments ModelAdmin init using. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [get_form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form):

```
class SystemAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = SystemAdminForm

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        self.refresh()
        return super(SystemAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

    def refresh(self, request, obj):
        avahi = AvahiServiceDetector(self.update)

    def update(self, name, address, port):
        ip = IP.objects.get_or_create(address=address)
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. I'm new to python and django, so it was not obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) class in order to intercept all the requests before they reach any view.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/

Cheers